# I am trying to append a to an existing file. Why do I need to use .write and get an error when I used .append

Tags: python, python-3.x

I don't understand why I can't use append when I am appending to a file.

This is my code:

```
# opening capital.txt and append to it
files = open('capitals.txt', 'a') 
userInput = input('Type the name of the city you want to add on capitals: ')

# If I change this to files.write it works
files.append(f'{userInput}') 
files.close()
```

I just need an explanation of why `.write` works but not `.append`

When I use `.append` I get this error:

```
> AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'
```

Comment: Why do you think `'_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'`? What made you think it would have an `append` method anyway?

Comment: BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour] and [ask].

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you append to a file in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706499/how-do-you-append-to-a-file-in-python)

Comment: [TextIOWrapper has no append](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.TextIOWrapper).

Comment: "I just need an explanation why .write works but not .append" because, as the error message clearly states, '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'append'. What exactly are you asking? Are you asking *why* that is the case? Because the answer to that is: because the designers of the API wrote it that way.

Comment: it doesnt work because append is not a class method, it doesnt exist... write does...and when you open a file using 'append' write method, it means when you write, you are appending

Comment: @DerekEden Thank you that explain it clearly and concise. Exactly the answer I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

`files` is an instance of  `_io.TextIOWrapper`

```
In [14]: isinstance(files, _io.TextIOWrapper)                                                                                                                  
Out[14]: True
```

Also, `files` does not have the `append` function:

```
In [15]: hasattr(_io.TextIOWrapper, "write")                                                                                                                  
Out[15]: True

In [16]: hasattr(_io.TextIOWrapper, "append")                                                                                                                 
Out[16]: False
```

I think this is a more pythonic version of your code:

```
with open("capitals.txt", "a") as log:
    msg = input("Type the name of the city: ")
    log.write("{}\n".format(msg))
```

Answer (score -2):

Switch out the append command and put write. (Keep 'a'). This is because there is an append command; however, that is used for adding an element to a list, whereas the write command will edit a file.

Comment: You should explain your answer rather than just telling OP what to do.